# Making radio buttons that are named differently, act as if they were in a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically generated form - within it are multiple fieldsets with their own elements. Among those is a radio button. Here's a simplified snippet:

```
    <form name="ePIC" method="post" action="test.php">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" name="pic[1]" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" name="pic[2]" />
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="test" />
    </form>
```

Basically, in the fieldsets are pictures and the radio buttons are to select the cover picture for the album.

Everything is working great except the fact that, because the radio buttons are named differently, they won't act as a group - meaning, multiple radio buttons can be selected at once.

Can anyone tell me how to make the radio buttons act as a group, probably with javascript/jQuery?

I started trying to manage the buttons by class - but got lost along the way as to how to affect all the other radio buttons, at the click of one.

Comment: Why can they not have the same name?

Comment: How are the radio buttons that should be part of the same group supposed to be found? Will they all have the same name except for the `[n]` part?

Comment: it's hard to put into words, but it's because each fieldset represents an item. And the elements in those fieldsets represent a property of that item. The item itself, I need to keep track of as an index - so, I pass my elements as arrays (i.e. <input type="textbox" name="first[<?php echo id; ?>]" />

Comment: @Barmar, yes - they will all have the same name except for their indexes

Comment: basically, it's a radio button that is supposed to select a cover pictures from within a range of picture, in an album. The pictures serve as the group - and the radio buttons need to act accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery code will remove the `[n]` part of all the radio button names, so all the buttons with the same name prefix will be grouped together.

```
$(":radio").attr('name', function(i, name) {
    $(this).data('orig-name', name);
    return name.replace(/\[.*\]/, '');
});
```

Use this `submit` handler to put back the original names with the indexes when the form is submitted.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(':radio').attr('name', function() {
        return $(this).data('orig-name');
    });
});
```

Comment: when I post the form, will the radio buttons retain their indexes?

Comment: No, they won't. You should use the value to know which button was selected in each group.

Comment: I will give it a go with the value, and see how it goes.

Comment: I've added code that saves the original name and puts it back when the form is submitted. But you really should use radio buttons the way they're intended to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You better use same name, but if  you can't:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    // Deselect all
    $('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false);
    // Select current
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: before I accept your answer, I'll give it a try using the values of the radio buttons to retain the picture id, instead of using an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same `name` for both radio button, only one will be allowed to be selected. Take a look at the code below.

```
 <form name="ePIC" method="post" action="test.php">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" name="pic" value="1" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" name="pic" value="2" />
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="test" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create them with the same name but you can assign them different values with the `value` attribute.